# How to call function from watch?

Tags: vue.js

```
data: function ()  {
    return {
       questions: []
    }
},

watch: {
    questions : function(val, oldVal) {
        foo()
    }
},      

methods: {
    foo() {
        console.log("foo called");
    }
}
```

Produce error: `ReferenceError: foo is not defined`

Also I am looking at examples: http://vuejs-ru.github.io/vuejs.org/api/options.html#watch

What this string do?

`handler: function (val, oldVal) { /* ... */ },`
`handler` it's keyword? Or it can be function?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you want to use watch to observe your property, you could call your method it with `this.foo`:

```js
data: function ()  {
    return {
       questions: []
    }
},
    
watch: {
   questions: {
       handler: function(val, oldVal) {
           this.foo(); // call it in the context of your component object
       },
       deep: true
    }
},      
    
methods: {
    foo() {
        console.log("foo called");
    }
}
```

To answer your question about `handler`: It is a keyword property that can take either a function expression (as in the example) or a reference to a function, such as:

```js
function myHandler() { ... } // Defined somewhere outside of the vue component object
    
...
    
handler: myHandler,
    
...
```

Just out of curiosity: Do you need to watch a property in order to do something every time it changes or could [computed properties](http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html) solve your problem as well?

Comment: Am I right understand that on every data changing `foo` will call?
I need to check my data to changes on every user click on checkbox. So is `watch` enough for me? 

Now I change values of `question` structure with `v-model="firstLevelAnswer.isSelected"`. 

And now I do not see any changes on console when I am clicking on checkboxes. I expect that foo well be called every time when the `data` are changing.

Comment: What is `firstLevelAnswer`? With your code, you are only watching for changes to `questions`. The name of the key in the `watch` object is the property that you're going to watch.

Comment: here is my questions: http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?6blwxsym1kmm

Here main part of my project: http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?yptv4v76qqmi

Comment: In this case, you're probably easier off listening to `input` events on your question in the dom: vuejs.org/guide/events.html

Comment: Nothing in general. It just takes a lot more effort to get watch to do what you want to do (also performance-wise).

Comment: And why on every click on checkbox function `foo()` do not calling? I thought that click are changing `questions` state

Comment: Because watch doesn't usually track deep changes. You can use the `deep` option, if you want to (I updated the example).

Comment: @nill, big thanks, but code that I uploaded to everfall already have `deep` function, but it now working :(

Comment: Oh, you missed `}` in your code. Why it's do not work without `handler`?

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to the answer from @nils

```
handler: 'foo'
```

also works if the function foo is within methods.

Bit shorter than

```
handler() {
    this.foo()
}
```

Comment: Very clean. Note when using this approach with a Vuex state variable, for example `'$store.state.questions': 'foo'` the (value, oldValue) parameters pass through so foo() becomes `foo(value, oldValue){}`.